# Minimum element on each row and column

Tags: matrix, row, each, minimum

This might sound stupid but I can't get it to work. 
After reading how many rows and how many columns a matrix has, I'm trying to display the minimum element on each row, then the minimum element on each column.

My code looks like this, but sometimes it throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException, sometimes it just doesnt display the minimum for the columns, only for the rows.

The code for the rows, which works, is this

```
public static void minRand(int[][] n) {

    int[] result = new int[n.length];
    int min = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n[0].length; j++) {
            if (n[i][j] < n[i][min]) {
                min = j;
            }
            result[i] = n[i][min];
        }
        System.out.println("Minimum on line " + i + " is " + result[i]);
    }

}
```

And the code for the columns, which does not work is

```
public static void minCol(int[][] n) {

    int[] result = new int[n[0].length];
    int min = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n.length; ++i) {
            min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            for (int j = 1; j < n[i].length; ++j)
                if (n[j][i] < min)
                    min = n[j][i];
            System.out.println("Minimum on column no " + i + " is " + min);
        }

}
```

If i give it 3 lines and 4 columns, the console displays this:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
        at Principal.minCol(Principal.java:103)
        at Principal.afisareMeniu(Principal.java:196)
        at Principal.main(Principal.java:13)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Minimum on line 0 este 0
Minimum on line 1 este 0
Minimum on line 2 este 0
```

It's 0 because i didnt initialize the matrix, but the minimum on each line works.

**Also. If i give it a square matrix, both the minimum for rows and columns work.**
What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Minimum in Column
 public static void colMin(double[][] n){
    double[] result = new double[n.length];
    double min = 0;
    System.out.println("Column min values: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; ++i) {
        min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int j = 1; j < n[i].length; ++j)
            if (n[j][i] < min){
                min = n[j][i];
                result[i] = min;
            }

        System.out.printf("%.2f ", result[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Just Assign your computed min to result[i] as shown above in my code.
and display.

Cheers.

Comment: That works, but I figured it out. I was considering the number of rows to be the number of columns and vice versa. Thanks for the effort